# ruby, no method error

Tags: ruby

I am receiving the following error when running my below ruby script:

```
s3parse.rb:12:in `block in <class:AccountLog>': undefined method `extract_account_id' for AccountLog:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I dont think it should be a class method, is there a reason its not taking my method into account?

```
class AccountLog
attr_accessor :bytes, :account_id, :date

    def extract_account_id(line)
            line.match(%r{accounts/(\d+)}).captures.join.to_i
    end

    s3log = File.open('vidcoder.txt').each do |line|
        account_log = AccountLog.new
        account_log.date = line.match(%r{\[[^:]*}).to_s.delete"[" #need to finish this regex to make it work
        account_log.account_id = extract_account_id(line)
        account_log.bytes = line.match(%r{^.*\s+HTTP.*\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+}).captures.join.to_i
        puts "\n" 
        puts "The api request on #{account_log.date} was fromm account number #{account_log.account_id} and the bytes were #{account_log.bytes}"
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you post s3parse.rb or at least the relevant parts that are making use of the AccountLog class?

Comment: Hi- that is the entire class and file, I am just running that file from the command line, my goal was to refactor out the regular expressions into individual methods to make it read better

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that s3log variable? If that's a ruby script you should just move that logic outside of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def extract_account_id` will define an instance method.

In the way you call it, you need a class method instead.

Define it like this:

```
def self.extract_account_id(line)
```

or, as you already have an `AccountLog` instance, use it to call `extract_account_id`:

```
account_log.account_id = account_log.extract_account_id(line)
```

Please note that with second way you do not need to alter method definition, just call `extract_account_id` via `account_log` instance.

And i guess you would want to put `s3log = File...` outside class definition.

Or use a constant instead: `S3log = ...`

Then you'll can access it as `AccountLog::S3log`

Comment: thank you everyone. I changed it to account_log.extract_account_id(line) and it works properly. Since the extraction of the account ID should be on an instance (an individual s3log) I think it makes sense to use an instance method and not a class method.

Comment: @BC00 I might be wrong but you're extracting the ID from a file line to store it in the instance. That sounds more like the job of a class method not an instance method. Even if you don't have an instance of an AccountLog you should still be able to extract the ID from a line of text no?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you don't think it should be a class method? You are using it in the context of a class method and that's why it it's saying no such method for class AccountLog.

If you name your method as `self.extract_account_id(line)` I'm sure it will work.

From what you are trying to do I think this is what you are looking for?

```
class AccountLog
  attr_accessor :bytes, :account_id, :date

  def self.extract_account_id(line)
    line.match(%r{accounts/(\d+)}).captures.join.to_i
  end
end

s3log = File.open('vidcoder.txt').each do |line|
  account_log = AccountLog.new
  account_log.date = line.match(%r{\[[^:]*}).to_s.delete"[" #need to finish this regex to make it work
  account_log.account_id = extract_account_id(line)
  account_log.bytes = line.match(%r{^.*\s+HTTP.*\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+}).captures.join.to_i
  puts "\n" 
  puts "The api request on #{account_log.date} was fromm account number #{account_log.account_id} and the bytes were #{account_log.bytes}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could take the class method approach, there seems to be a little more going on.

You should put the extraction logic in a method in itself rather than let it hangout in your class. Then outside of the class, have an instance of AccountLog where you can call on the methods for log and account id extraction. At that point you can do something with those values.

Class method or not is a detail we can explore after the class is a bit more clean I think.